# Jmeter - Calling javascript using JSR223 Post processor

Tags: jmeter, correlation, jsr223

I capture 6 elements using a regular expression. say

```
Variable : UserDetails
Regular Expression : loadHeadWorkFlow\('(.+?)','(.+?)','(.+?)','(.+?)','(.+?)','(.+?)','/I
Template : $1$$2$$3$$4$$5$$6$
```

Now I could access these values via UserDetails_g1, UserDetails_g2.....UserDetails_g6

Next, these 6 values need to be encrypted using a javascript file. The file contains the logic.

How should my code be using JSR223 post processor?

The steps that I followed:

1.

```
load('Encryption.js');

   var result = encrypt("${UserDetails_g1}","password");
   log.info("encrypted value is "+result);
   vars.put("LoginDataString",result);

   var result1 = encrypt("${UserDetails_g2}","password1");
   vars.put("UserId",result1);

   var result2 = encrypt("${UserDetails_g3}","password2");
   vars.put("RoleId",result2);
```

First value is encrypted correctly. But the other values aren't correct. If I add individual post processors for every variable. All the encrypted values show correctly.

Is there a way where I could use a single post processor to perform all the 6 encryptions. Thanks in advance

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vars` instead of `${}` syntax

```
 var result = encrypt(vars.get("UserDetails_g1"),"password");
 log.info("encrypted value is "+result);
 vars.put("LoginDataString",result);

 var result1 = encrypt(vars.get("UserDetails_g2"),"password1");
 vars.put("UserId",result1);

 var result2 = encrypt(vars.get("UserDetails_g3"),"password2");
 vars.put("RoleId",result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

From JMeter perspective there is no problems, just check that your `UserDetails_g2` variable has anticipated value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script), the you might want to check this `encrypt()` function implementation.

Another possible reason is this JavaScript language selection itself, the Nashorn engine performance is a big question mark when it comes to the load, according to JMeter Best Practices [it's recommended to use Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) so you might want to consider re-writing the function in Groovy

Comment: I have replied to your message in my answer. please consider that and provide me a solution. I will consider the groovy scripting part later.